# Custom View inside HorizontalScrollView, surfaceCreated not getting called

Tags: android, surfaceview, custom-view

I am trying to have a CustomView inside a `HorizontalScrollView`.
In the Root layout there are three Layouts, `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout` and in the end `HorizontalScrollView`.

I am adding a custom view which extends surface view.
The Layout XML is as below

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <FrameLayout>
    ..
    ..
    </FrameLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
    ..
    ..
    </RelativeLayout        
    <HorizontalScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/audio_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="90dip"
    android:background="@drawable/controller_bgnd" 
    >
    <com.com.ffplayer.AudioWaveView
    android:id="@+id/audio_waves"
    android:layout_width="500dip"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    />

    </HorizontalScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Here `AudioWaveView` is a custom view which `extends SurfaceView`.
But the `surfaceCreated` function is never getting called.
Please let me know anything has to be done if custom view needs to be implemented within `HorizontalScrollView` or if it is a sibling of other layouts in a Root Layout.
Because I have implemented similar custom view as just a single view within a Root Layout and it worked.

Comment: Add code properly, here unable to see the xml code

Comment: sorry, I have just edited it